# RESTful API response in Laravel 5

Tags: php, rest, http, laravel, laravel-5

I'm building RESTful API with Laravel. My API always returns JSON. What I would like to do, is keeping response logic at one place. Here's how I do it right now in API controller, which is pointed to by `Route::controller()`. Funny and ultra-useful example coming:

```
public function getDouble($number) {
    try {
        if (!is_numeric($number)) {
            throw new HttpException(400, 'Invalid number.');
        }

        $response = $number * 2;
        $status = 200;
    }
    catch (HttpException $exception) {
        $response = $exception->getMessage();
        $status   = $exception->getStatusCode();
    }

    return response()->json($response, $status);
}
```

In this example, my API route would be for example `/double/13` accessed by GET method. The problem is that I repeat this try ... catch block in each method. I would like my API methods to be like:

```
public function getDouble($number) {
    if (!is_numeric($number)) {
        throw new HttpException(400, 'Invalid number.');
    }

    return $number;
}
```

And then, catch those exceptions and form JSON in another place. What is the best approach here in terms of good application architecture?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Response on Exception

You could do this by handling the exception in `App\Exceptions\Handler`.

You could do it in the render method, likeso :

```
/**
 * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Exception  $e
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if($e instanceof HttpException) {
        return response()->json($e->getMessage(), $e->getStatusCode());
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

## Success Response

There are several ways to do this but I guess Middleware would be the best suited one right.

- Create a middleware (say, ApiResponseFormatterMiddleware)
- In your 'App\Http\Kernel', add it to `$routeMiddleware` array.
- Apply it to the api routes, response to which you want to parse.

You could do something in the lines of :

```
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $response = $next($request);

    return response()->json($response->getOriginalContent());
}
```

Ofcourse, you need to change a bit of logic to parse the content the way you want it, but skeleton remains the same.

Comment: `$response` when casted to string will give the rendered string. Its intended behaviour.

Comment: Yes, but I did `var_dump` on $response in my Middleware and it says it's a string, not an object.

Comment: By the way, is there any better way then registering global Exception handler? I would like to handle ordinary Exceptions for my API as well, but the way I handle them there is differenc than outside API.

Comment: You could do it by other means (like: using a catch all -api- route) but they are cumbersome and will need you to sacrifice a few laravel benefits. Better use the `$request` to determine if the request is for your api or the rest of the app.